# "Storm" data handling capability

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-storm

For a business use case where we have to deal with minimum "2-3 terabyte" of data per day, I was doing analysis on "Hadoop & Storm".

Needless to say that “Storm” looks impressive because of its efficiency in processing incoming big data but I am not sure whether “Storm” will be capable enough to process “Terabyte” of data and at the same time providing me real-time results or not ?

Can anyone explain please?

Thanks,
Gajendra

Comment: Exabyte? What on earth takes that much space?

Comment: I don't know if *anything* could process exabytes per day, you'd need quite a bit of hardware just to *get* the data, let alone do any sort of analysis. For example, Google might be processing a few exabytes of data per day, and they have a million servers. So good luck.

Comment: just confirmed that it wouldn't be exabyte rather it would be few terabyte

Comment: However, the spirit of this question was to know that among "Hadoop & Storm" whose data accepetance capacity is more.

Comment: What is your requirement? Realtime or batch analytics?

Comment: It depends on business function. Few business functions like operations & project management expect real time analystics whereas others can live with batch. But data in either case would be huge, very huge that I can assure you. So, if real time analytics not able to process my huge business data then there is no logic to go ahead with it. In that case I guess I have to live with batch analytics only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storm was developed by twitter. they process more than 8 TB per day with it. Sounds like this should be enough for your case. Afaik storm is the best streaming/realtime system for distributed computing. hadoop is not suitable for it due to job start up times and not native handling of streaming data.

a fact is, both can handle the data per day you wish when you have enough server power and storage etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response "merando".